# How do I dynamically add an jquery ui event handler to a dynamically created button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a jquery ui modal dialog box form that adds items to a table.  One of the table columns is my link to edit the row in question.  This is a button object and I want to add an event handler that when the user clicks on the button, it run a ajax query to pull back the information for the selected lines ID and display that data in a form for the user to edit the selected row.

I am trying to get it to use the same function

```
$( ".edit-user" )
  .button()
  .click(function() {
    //do something here
});
```

Here the code that create the dynamic row with the edit button.  I am trying to get the "click" event handler to be attached to the dynamically created button.

```
        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td><button class=\"edit-user\" id=\"edit-user-15\">Edit</button></td>" +
          "<td>" + mc_last_name.val() + "</td>" +
          first_name +
          "<td>" + mc_primary_address.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + mc_primary_city.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + mc_primary_state.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + mc_primary_zipcode.val() + "</td>" +
          phone + 
          email_address +
          "<td>" + mc_primary_addcommunity.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );

        $(".edit-user").on('click','button',function(){
            var parameters = {
                "cid":this.id.replace(/\D/g,"")
            };

        $.ajax({
                url : "./getcontact.php",
                type: "POST",
                data : parameters,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    var arr = data.split('|||');

                    $.each(arr,function(key,value) {
                        var temp = value.split(':::')
                        $("#" + temp[0]).val(temp[1]);
                    });

                    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                  alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
```

I have tried several different options:

```
 $('#edit-user-15').on('click', 'button', function() {
     //Run the display form function.
 });

 $('#edit-user-15').delegate('click', 'button', function() {
     //Run the display form function.
 });
```

I am relatively new to jquery...so these kinds of weird errors are hard to explain what I am trying to do.

Looking for thoughts on how to make the any button on the table to use the special function?

Thannks
jlimted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Something like this :

```
function appendButton(){
  $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td><button class=\"edit-user\" id=\"edit-user-15\">Edit</button></td>" +
          "<td>" + mc_last_name.val() + "</td>" +
          first_name +
          "<td>" + mc_primary_address.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + mc_primary_city.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + mc_primary_state.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + mc_primary_zipcode.val() + "</td>" +
          phone + 
          email_address +
          "<td>" + mc_primary_addcommunity.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );

}
```

And predefine the handler of class `.edit-user` as

```
$(document).on("click",".edit-user",function(){
 //Your On Click part here 

});
```

Here is the working [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SSDRU/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$( "#users tbody" ).on('click','.edit-user',function(){})

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). Thus in the above code, "#users tbody" must exist before the code is generated whereas before it was "#edit-user-15" which didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

check this out. http://jsfiddle.net/Wu7aX/

the `$(".edit-user")` is meant to be a parent of the `button` argument to the `on` method.
Something more like this may would work for you.
`$("body").on('click','button.edit-user', function(){
    var parameters = {
        "cid":this.id.replace(/\D/g,"")
     };
...`

This way every time you click the body element jquery will check to see if the click came from a `button` element inside of an element with the class `edit-user`.